# OpenXML spacing troubles

Tags: c#, openxml

I am creating a word document(2010) using c#.

It consists of a large table weith cells and within the cells paragraphs.

I Have achieved this with a little with (i hope simple) a little niggly issue. In front of every piece of text there is a block of empty space.[image]

I am attempting to get rid of this space with no luck.

To build the table I have pretty much followed this example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg490656.aspx

I have tried fiddling with the sacing of the cells, of the table rows and of the table cells but i'm unsure if i am using the right properties.

I have tried appending new ContextualSpacing() { Val = false } to table row and cells with no luck. I've also tried new Spacing with no luck either!

Any ideas hints tips would be muchly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that setting the style to a style within word resolved the issue. This was a manual process and then i looked in to how to do this programatically.

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableStyle tableStyle2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableStyle() { Val = "TableGrid" };
```

Append this item to the table and it all worked perfectly!